# how can i execute query inside the foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

So after selecting some column and rows from database i have to put them into array, to put them into array,i use the foreach loop, and it worked. Then while it's looping through the query result, i need to execute some queries that based on the vealue of query result  on where the looping still working.But i got eror. this is my code. can you guys help fix this? i am new to Php so i have no idea to fix it.

```
            <?php

        require("config.php");

        $whatvenue= $_POST['whatvenue'];
        $showby= $_POST['showedby'];

        if($whatvenue==="hotel")
        {
            $query = "Select * FROM venues where venue_category like :whatvenue";

        }
        else if($whatvenue==="restoran")
        {
            $query = "Select * FROM venues where venue_category like :whatvenue";
        }
        else
        {
            $query = "Select * FROM venues where venue_category like :whatvenue";
        }


         $query_params = array(
                ':whatvenue' => $_POST['whatvenue']
            );
        try 
        {
            $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) 
        {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
            die(json_encode($response));
        }
        $queryreviews ="SELECT COUNT( VENUE_ID) AS TOTALREVIEWER   FROM COMMENT WHERE VENUE_ID =:venue_id";
        $queryrsb     ="SELECT COUNT( USER_ID ) AS TOTALREVIEWERSB FROM COMMENT WHERE VENUE_ID =:venue_id AND REVIEW_RATE =5";
        $queryrb      ="SELECT COUNT( USER_ID ) AS TOTALREVIEWERB  FROM COMMENT WHERE VENUE_ID =:venue_id AND REVIEW_RATE =4";
        $queryrc      ="SELECT COUNT( USER_ID ) AS TOTALREVIEWERC  FROM COMMENT WHERE VENUE_ID =:venue_id AND REVIEW_RATE =3";
        $queryrk      ="SELECT COUNT( USER_ID ) AS TOTALREVIEWERK  FROM COMMENT WHERE VENUE_ID =:venue_id AND REVIEW_RATE =2";
        $queryrsk     ="SELECT COUNT( USER_ID ) AS TOTALREVIEWERSK FROM COMMENT WHERE VENUE_ID =:venue_id AND REVIEW_RATE =1";

        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        if ($rows) 
        {
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Venue Ditampilkan!";
            $response["venues"]   = array();

            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $venues             = array();
                $venues["venue_id"]         = $row["VENUE_ID"];
                $query_paramsr = array(
                ':venue_id' => $venues["venue_id"] 
                );
                try 
                {
                    $stmtr    = $db->prepare($queryreviews);
                    $resultr  = $stmtr->execute($query_paramsr);

                    $stmtrsb   = $db->prepare($queryrsb);
                    $resultsb  = $stmtrsb->execute($query_paramsr);

                    $stmtrb    = $db->prepare($queryrb);
                    $resultrb  = $stmtrb->execute($query_paramsr);

                    $stmtrc    = $db->prepare($queryrc);
                    $resultrc  = $stmtrc->execute($query_paramsr);

                    $stmtrk    = $db->prepare($queryrk);
                    $resultrk  = $stmtrk->execute($query_paramsr);

                    $stmtrsk   = $db->prepare($queryrsk);
                    $resultrsk = $stmtrsk->execute($query_paramsr);
                }
                catch (PDOException $ex) 
                {
                    $response["success"] = 0;
                    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
                    die(json_encode($response));
                }

                $rowsr   = $stmtr ->fetch();
                $rowsrsb = $stmtrsb->fetch();
                $rowsrb  = $stmtrb->fetch();
                $rowsrc  = $stmtrc->fetch();
                $rowsrk  = $stmtrk->fetch();
                $rowsrsk = $stmtrsk->fetch();

                $venues["venue_totalreviwer"]   = $rowsr  ["TOTALREVIEWER"];
                $venues["venue_totalreviwersb"] = $rowsrsb["TOTALREVIEWERSB"];
                $venues["venue_totalreviwerb"]  = $rowsrb ["TOTALREVIEWERB"];
                $venues["venue_totalreviwerc"]  = $rowsrc["TOTALREVIEWERC"];
                $venues["venue_totalreviwerk"]  = $rowsrk["TOTALREVIEWERK"];
                $venues["venue_totalreviwersk"] = $rowsrsk["TOTALREVIEWERSK"];
                $venues["venue_name"]        = $row["VENUE_NAME"];
                $venues["venue_address"]     = $row["VENUE_ADDRESS"];
                $venues["venue_desc"]        = $row["VENUE_DESC"];
                $venues["venue_lat"]         = $row["VENUE_LAT"];
                $venues["venue_long"]        = $row["VENUE_LONG"];
                $venues["venue_category"]    = $row["VENUE_CATEGORY"];
                $venues["venue_phone"]       = $row["VENUE_PHONE"];
                $venues["venue_email"]       = $row["VENUE_EMAIL"];
                $venues["venue_website"]     = $row["VENUE_WEBSITE"];
                $venues["venue_picture"]     = $row["VENUE_PICTURE"];
                $venues["venue_rating"]      = $row["VENUE_RATING"];


                //update our repsonse JSON data
                array_push($response["venues"], $venues);
            }

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);

        } 
        else 
        {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Venue yang diminta tidak tersedia";
            die(json_encode($response));
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: Please don't make database calls inside a loop. Use a join.

Comment: is there any tutorial that i can read to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to hit your database several times when you can grab all the information you need in one go. A possible version of your base query which do exactly that might look like

```sql
SELECT v.venue_id
      ,q.totalreviewersb
      ,q.totalreviewerb
      ,q.totalreviewerc
      ,q.totalreviewerk
      ,q.totalreviewersk
      ,v.venue_name
      ,v.venue_address
      ,v.venue_desc
      ,v.venue_lat
      ,v.venue_long
      ,v.venue_category
      ,v.venue_phone
      ,v.venue_email
      ,v.venue_website
      ,v.venue_picture
      ,v.venue_rating
  FROM venus v JOIN
(
  SELECT v.venue_id
        ,COUNT(*) totalreviewer
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.review_rate = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalreviewersb
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.review_rate = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalreviewerb
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.review_rate = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalreviewerc
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.review_rate = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalreviewerk
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.review_rate = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalreviewersk
    FROM venus v LEFT JOIN comment c 
      ON v.venue_id = c.venue_id
   WHERE v.venue_category LIKE :whatvenue
   GROUP BY v.venue_id
) q ON v.venue_id = q.venue_id
```

Now your php code might be boiled down to something like this

```php
<?php
require('config.php');

$whatvenue= $_POST['whatvenue'];
//$showby= $_POST['showedby'];

$query = 'SELECT 
       v.venue_id
      ,q.totalreviewersb
      ,q.totalreviewerb
      ,q.totalreviewerc
      ,q.totalreviewerk
      ,q.totalreviewersk
      ,v.venue_name
      ,v.venue_address
      ,v.venue_desc
      ,v.venue_lat
      ,v.venue_long
      ,v.venue_category
      ,v.venue_phone
      ,v.venue_email
      ,v.venue_website
      ,v.venue_picture
      ,v.venue_rating
  FROM venus v JOIN
(
  SELECT v.venue_id
        ,COUNT(*) totalreviewer
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.review_rate = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalreviewersb
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.review_rate = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalreviewerb
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.review_rate = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalreviewerc
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.review_rate = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalreviewerk
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN c.review_rate = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalreviewersk
    FROM venus v LEFT JOIN comment c 
      ON v.venue_id = c.venue_id
   WHERE v.venue_category LIKE :whatvenue
   GROUP BY v.venue_id
) q ON v.venue_id = q.venue_id';

try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(':whatvenue' => $whatvenue));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response['success'] = 0;
    $response['message'] = 'Database Error!';
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$response['success'] = 1;
$response['message'] = 'Venue Ditampilkan!';
$response['venues' ] = rows();

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
```

***Note:** Obviously the provided code example hasn't been tested*

Comment: IT WORKED!!!, Thank you so much Peterm :D, thank you so much! i've been dealing with it for 6 hours, thank you. you saved my day.Thanks a lot :D.